# multer-gridfs error " TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_id') "

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, gridfs, multer-gridfs-storage

I'm working on creating a WhatsApp clone and implementing a file sharing feature. Everything was going smoothly until I encountered this error that's causing my backend to crash. The strange thing is, I can see the file in MongoDB, but the error persists. I'm hoping someone can help me troubleshoot this issue.

Here's a summary of what's happening:

I have a file sharing feature in my WhatsApp clone app.
When a user tries to share a file, it's saved to MongoDB.
I can confirm that the file exists in the MongoDB database.
However, the backend crashes with an error that I can't seem to resolve.
I'm not sure where to begin troubleshooting this issue. Can anyone provide insights on what might be causing this problem? Is there a common mistake I might be making when dealing with file sharing in a MongoDB database?

i cant post all my code here my question will be too long [here is my github link][1]

api.js

```
export const uploadFile = async (data) => {
    try {
        return await axios.post(`${url}/file/upload`, data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error while calling uploadfile API ', error);
    }
}
```

controller

```
const url = 'http://localhost:8000';
export const uploadFile = async(request, response)=>{
    if(!request.file){
        return response.status(404).json("file not found")
    }
    const imageUrl = `${url}/file/${request.file.filename}`;
    return response.status(200).json(imageUrl);
}
```

route.js

```
//Route for file upload
route.post('/file/upload', upload.single("file"), uploadFile);
```

error

```
C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\webdev\whatsapp clone self\server\node_modules\multer-gridfs-storage\lib\gridfs.js:306
                        id: f._id,
                              ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_id')       
    at GridFSBucketWriteStream.emitFile (C:\Users\Siddh\OneDrive\Documents\webdev\whatsapp clone self\server\node_modules\multer-gridfs-storage\lib\gridfs.js:306:31)
    at GridFSBucketWriteStream.emit (node:events:526:35)
    at finish (node:internal/streams/writable:807:10)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)

Node.js v20.9.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: You are sending the file data in JSON, since axios picks up the second arguement as a default JSON object. You have to select `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: Check this example request: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51587173/6072570

Comment: The data is sent as `multipart/form-data` and is of type `FormData`.

Comment: @TrishantPahwa i tried this too ``` axios({
            method : "post",
            url:`${url}/file/upload`,
            data : datas,
            headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' }
        });``` i also added header but still app crashing and network tab showing network error

Comment: @TrishantPahwa here datas is the data function receiving from FormData

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Title: Solution for multer-gridfs error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_id')"

Answer:

It appears that you're encountering an issue with multer-gridfs that could be related to compatibility with your MongoDB version. To resolve this problem, consider downgrading your MongoDB version to one that is compatible with multer and multer-gridfs. Here's a step-by-step guide:

**1. Uninstall MongoDB:**

```
npm uninstall MongoDB
```

**2. Install Compatible Version (e.g., 5.9.1):**

```
npm install mongodb@5.9.1
```

This should help resolve the "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_id')" issue you're facing. Ensure to restart your Node.js application after making these changes.

Additionally, it's essential to check the compatibility matrix of multer-gridfs with MongoDB versions. Upgrading or downgrading packages can sometimes introduce other compatibility issues, so it's recommended to review the documentation and release notes for both multer-gridfs and MongoDB.

If the problem persists or if you encounter any other issues during the process, feel free to provide more details or ask for further assistance.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/10871073

Comment: hi my project not that big so downgrading really helped me thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Its seems that the multer is not compatible with the latest mongodb so
in your backend folder
install the mongodb version 5.9.1
npm i mongodb@5.9.1

for more info see
https://github.com/devconcept/multer-gridfs-storage/issues/560